# Declaration of dependent type as function parameter in template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gcc, dependent-type

I have a template class which has dependant types as typedefs used as function parameters :

```
template <typename T > struct Foo {
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator Iterator;

    inline void bar( const Iterator& it ) const;

    std::vector<T> vec;
};
```

Now, Visual Studio (2015) and GCC (5) have conflicting views over the correct declaration of function `bar()` outside of class `Foo`.

I originately wrote it like this on Linux, which GCC compiled happily :

```
template <typename T>
inline void Foo<T>::bar( const Foo<T>::Iterator& it ) const {}
```

Now trying to compile on Visual Studio 2015, I get the following error message

```
1>main.cpp(14): error C2065: 'it': undeclared identifier
1>main.cpp(14): warning C4346: 'Foo<T>::Iterator': dependent name is not a type
1>  main.cpp(14): note: prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
```

So it appears that VS requires the `typename` keyword to be present in front of `Iterator`. Fine. I added it, but now it refuses to compile in GCC.

```
main.cpp:14:35: error: variable or field 'bar' declared void
 inline void Foo<T>::bar( typename const Foo<T>::Iterator& it ) const {}
```

You can see it live here http://ideone.com/EaUeus

So my question is... who is right ? Is there a way to get this code to compile across both platform without resorting to `#ifdef`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `const typename`, not `typename const`. Compiler can't know that `Foo<T>::Iterator` is a type, and `const` can be used only for types. So first say it's a type, and then make it `const`.

Comment: Ah, man I should have thought about this, you were right. Good catch.